# calling managed beans that reside in other application(s)

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean, xpages-ssjs

In an XPages application I need to display information that resides in another XPage application.

I am used to use a Repeat control and use JavaScript to make a call to a managed bean for the data-binding.

Example:

```
<xp:repeat value="{#javascript:ArticleController.loadArticles();};>
```

I would like to keep the code and logic in the exisitng application but call and display the results in the second application. Is this possible and how should I do so?

Comment: Many possibilities are open such as a web service or moving Java code to a jar file on the server.

Comment: I think you can do this using ajax

Comment: can you give some more guidance on the web service? I assume you mean the xe:restService control since there I can define a serviceBean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String text = "{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}";        
try {
    response.getWriter().write(text);
    response.getWriter().close();
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

You can view the json in your browser with a plugin e.g. JSONView for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Each XPage runs in its own JVM, so the managed bean in Application B cannot be directly interacted with from Application A. Using the JSON RPC Service in the Extension Library you will be able to call an XAgent from Application B (that's effectively the same as a web service, but returning JSON rather than XML).

It may be worth reconsidering splitting the application logic. I've done that in the past, but my preference now is to keep all the web application logic in the same database, because each is a separate JVM:

- There's an initial performance hit for both XPages applications
- Each will have separate scopes, so applicationScope, sessionScope etc can't be shared
- You can share not only managed beans, but also utility code
- It's the method of architecture for Bluemix, keeping data and application separate
- You can further restrict access to the data by preventing URL access to the NSF itself

Comment: I read the following blog post: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9Q55QL since I got directed to use rest control and servicebean.  But I am not sure how to continue after setting the response header? (read: producing the json). Can I use a responsewriter as familiar with an "xagent"? I did not find much examples of code for a servicebean producing jspon...

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers: "Each XPage run in its own JVM"? This cannot be true, otherwise the SSJS problematic (extending the Array Prototype serverwide) would not exist...

Comment: Maybe that works similar to plugins, with the SSJS code scoped at server level? I know I've screwed up XPages runtime for a single app (e.g. infinite loop) which affects all attempts to open an XPage in that app, but it's fine for other apps.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers: If you do something like an infinite loop there is a protection on the server not to open new threads for a XPages instance (prevents DOS / DDOS etc). But there is only a single underlying JVM.